# Schedule task on precise periods in Linux or Windows

Tags: c++, windows, linux, embedded, interrupt

I have this weird question.
I would like to know if it is possible to make a program in C/C++ that will run on Linux or Windows and will hook interrupt handler on a system timer set to specific period (2000 times per second, for example) and I want this interrupt to be with highest priority, meaning that it has to be executed every half millisecond and while executing it must not be interrupted.

This we have done with MS-DOS with Borland Turbo C 3.1. We have an interface card (our own) that runs on ISA slot. Every half millisecond, our program reads the state of electronics that is controlling an industrial process thru the interface. This has worked for us in the past 15 years, but we are running out of motherboards that have ISA slot, so we are looking for new solutions.

We also have solution based on PIC microcontrollers, but our horizons will be widened with general purpose processor.

My guess is that there are some customized Linux kernels for embedded applications, so I am looking for some sources with which we can start experimenting.

Comment: Have you looked at custom hardware? Thanks to FPGAs it is much more affordable than it used to be. Look http://natami.net/  Firebee Atari and Minimig for instance.

Comment: If you go to Borland C++ instead of Turbo C, it is very compatible, but can generate (much larger) 32 bit DOS programs with DOS extenders http://www.thefreecountry.com/programming/dosextenders.shtml  Also look at DJGPP as Cody said, which is a more modern GNU compiler for DOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in MS-DOS because it is not a multi-user or multi-tasking operating system. However, the same thing will **not** work in Windows because it *is* a mult-user and multi-tasking operating system. It's also not real-time, which means there's no guarantee that your task will be executed *exactly* when you ask for it to be executed. Everything is pre-emptively scheduled, meaning that any number of other processes and tasks (either user-mode or system-level) could effectively "bump" your process down the priority list and force it to wait to be executed until those other tasks completed or were themselves interrupted to give your process a chance to run for a while.

I don't know about Linux, but I imagine most of the major distributions are written similarly to Windows.

You will need to find a real-time, single-user operating system to do this. A Unix-derivative is probably the best place to start looking, but I won't be the person able to suggest one.

Alternatively, you could continue using MS-DOS (or alternatives such as FreeDOS), but switch to a different interface technology that *is* available on newer boards. There's no reason to update something that works for you, especially if the updates are counter-productive to your goal.

Comment: +1 for MSDOS but with modern hardware. Also see FreeDOS, it might be compatible with more hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware how the OSes work and how they schedule tasks.
It is a good alternative to continue with FreeDOS. We were thinking about making interface card hooked on USB port. Suggestions about good c++ compiler and editor for FreeDOS would be great. Problem with Turbo C 3.1 is that it has source code length limitation.

Comment: @Gorgi: I don't know if FreeDOS supports USB drivers or not; better check that out before you commit to a USB host interface. And yeah, Turbo C is way too old to be actively using. You might try to find a version of GCC that can compile apps to run on DOS, or use something like [this](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/).

Comment: @Gorgi Rankovski, djgpp _is_ GCC.

Comment: Yes, looking back that was confusing phrasing. I meant to imply that I hadn't actually used djgpp personally.

Answer (score 2):

A typical OS such as a standard Linux or Windows is not designed to, and will not be able to perform to that degree of real-time accuracy and availability.

It sounds to me like you need to be investigating [Real-Time Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTLinux), or similar.

RTLinux is a modified version of the Linux Kernel which is designed to perform in real-time, precicely for applications such as this.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Personal and affordable computing has increased in performance incredibly over the years, except in one area, low latency. Latency has actually increased in many use cases when you compare a 486 and a modern desktop CPU.

That said, have a look at [this paper](https://netfiles.uiuc.edu/rajpal1/SoftRealTimeSchedulerPaper.pdf), where the authors come to the conclusion that sub-millisecond scheduling is possible in Linux on commodity hardware.

Comment: Are you sure that the difference is in the hardware rather than the software?

Comment: @Cody Gray, pretty sure yes. A cache miss in a 486 is pretty expensive, but the recovery time can only take so long. The worst case  cache miss on a modern CPU with huge L3, L2 and L1 caches is actually a pretty long-winded affair. I am talking about the worst case, not about average performance, which is of course incredibly high nowadays.

Comment: I am not saying older is better, but that there have been very modest improvements when it comes to latency.